# Get owner of the current view in Oracle

Tags: oracle, view

I want to create a view that containt a column which refers to the owner of this view. Something like that:

```
create or replace view scott.owner_v 
as
select something() owner from dual;
```

**Note**: `something()` shouldn't necessary be a function or package reference. It can be anything that gives a desired output.

So querying `select owner from scott.owner_v` under `JEREMY` user, for example, would return `SCOTT` and when I compile such view in `HR` schema I get `HR` in `owner` column.

Maybe seems dumb to query `SCOTT.owner_v` to get `SCOTT` but I need it in terms of building DWH referring to different sources which are situated in different schemas. So then I would build dynamically a new view which is on a "higher" level that collects data from all schemas with extra column like `owner` which shows a source of data. I can put this column when building this "higher" view but I want to keep it as simple as it can be.

Obviously, I tried to place into a view the following parameters

- sys_context('USERENV','CURRENT_USER')
- sys_context('USERENV','CURRENT_SCHEMA')
- user

but it refers to current logged user not to owner of the view.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you are building the view dynamically, why can't you then include the owner as a constant value - you should already have that name as you need (use) it in the CREATE statement anyway

Comment: I want to hold all the logic inside of "stage" schemas which hold source data. And on the next level you just have a view that UNIONs all the sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create local functions which returns own schemas in all schemas where do you want to create views:

```
create or replace function local_obj_owner return varchar2 as
begin
   return $$PLSQL_UNIT_OWNER;
end;
/
```

Then add it into your views:

```
create view test_view as
select
  local_obj_owner as view_owner,
  dummy
from dual;
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm on Oracle 11g so `$$PLSQL_UNIT_OWNER` returns NULL. But I changed it to `sys_context('USERENV', 'CURRENT_USER')` remembering that function is `AUTHID DEFINER`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select owner from all_views where view_name = 'OWNER_V';
```

and/or some alternatives (`USER_VIEWS`, `DBA_VIEWS`, `ALL_OBJECS`, ...).

Comment: It works if a view holding schema knows only about its view but I don't want to relate on not having grants on the same view in another schema.